# textFieldIndex (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have searched far and wide for an answer but I haven't found anything close.

The following code:

```
UIAlertView *welcome = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
                                                  message:@"Please Enter Your Credentials to Proceed"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[welcome show];
```

Gives the following **error**:

> textFieldIndex (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields

If I change the `alertView` type to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` then it works and I cant figure out why!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are calling `-textFieldAtIndex:` on an `alertView` object that does not or is not meant to have a `textField`.

Check for things like:

```
[welcome textFieldAtIndex:0];
```

or...

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //...
    [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    //...
}
```

---

This could be if you're using multiple `alertView` objects and haven't handled done case-handling to bifurcate the implementation for an `alertView` object that has a `textField` and another `alertView` that doesn't have a `textField`

Comment: In fact you are right. I also have this elsewhere: [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]; So what is the best way to handle multiple alterviews please?

Comment: thank you sorted: I added [alert setTag:1]; to the offending AlertView and then used if ([alertView tag] == 1) to ensure that this is only called when required. Is in good practice to tag all alertviews?

Comment: @user3740845 : yes, tags... that's how it's commonly done. you're on the right track :)